# How to save a subprocess output as a list of strings for further analysis?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
import os
import shlex, subprocess

cmd = "/usr/local/bin/gmx grompp -h"
args = shlex.split(cmd)
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = proc1.stdout.read()
print(output)
```

Basically I am using a program called gromacs. As you can see I am combining `stdout` and `stderr` so I can then just use `stdout.read()` and be able to get everything.

However, the `print(output)` is a mess and it has no format:

`b'                      :-) GROMACS - gmx grompp, 2018.3 (-:\n\n                            GROMACS is written by:\n     Emile Apol      Rossen Apostolov      Paul Bauer     Herman J.C. Berendsen\n    Par Bjelkmar    Aldert van Buuren   Rudi van Drunen     Anton Feenstra  \n  Gerrit Groenhof    Aleksei Iupinov   Christoph Junghans   Anca Hamuraru   \n Vincent Hindriksen Dimitrios Karkoulis    Peter Kasson        Jiri Kraus    \n  Carsten Kutzner      Per Larsson      Justin A. Lemkul    Viveca Lindahl  \n  Magnus Lundborg   Pieter Meulenhoff    Erik Marklund      Teemu Murtola   \n    Szilard Pall       Sander Pronk      Roland Schulz     Alexey Shvetsov  \n   Michael Shirts     Alfons Sijbers     Peter Tieleman    Teemu Virolainen \n Christian Wennberg    Maarten Wolf   \n                           and the project leaders:\n        Mark Abraham, Berk Hess, Erik Lindahl, and David van der Spoel\n\nCopyright (c) 1991-2000,`

All the `\n` is were there should be a new line.

What must I do in order to have a list of string were basically each string is a line of the output?

In other words:

```
output = [" :-) GROMACS - gmx grompp, 2018.3 (-:", "GROMACS is written by:", ..........]
```

Therefore, I can do things as output[i].find("2018") and other things as well.

when I put:

```
print(type(output))
```

I get:

```
<class 'bytes'>
```

It is very clear that I must do something else to get what I need but I have no idea what to do. I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: Try adding a `output = output.decode().splitlines()` before printing to turn it into a `str` and then split those into a list.

Comment: this is beautiful. Where did you find that decode? I looked all over subprocess and did not see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do what you want by adding the following line before printing the output:

```
output = output.decode().splitlines()
```

Calling `decode()` will turn the `bytes` into a python string (`str`), and the `splitlines()` turns that into a list-of-strings.

[`decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) is `bytes` method that decodes them into a string assuming they've been encoded in utf-8 (by default) — it's not documented in the `subprocessing` documentation (that I know of).